# How @mention works, how can I find mention during comment in .Net

Tags: .net, regex, indexof, mention

I need to know how mention works, how should find mentions during a text.
are we must to find first of **'@'** and last of **not @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_,]+$"**

thank you for sharing your experience

```
string comment=" hi @fri.tara3^";
mention is : "@fri.tara3"
```

Comment: You already know you can use regex for this. Is there a question somewhere? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: It's really hard to find last index of **not @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_,]+$"** , I don't know what should I do

Comment: @ara: what about [`@"@\S+\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/uH3wA3/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is magical! unbelievable , thank you man

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - while the principle is valid, `\S` is not the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_,]` and neither is `\b` matching the negation  class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a good fit for regular expressions. There are multiple ways to solve this.

**Here's the simplest one:**

```
 (?<mention>@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]
```

- it searches matching characters followed by non-matching character. `[^ ... ]` does the negation bit
- `(?<mention> ... )` declares an explictit group to capture mention without including the non-matching character immediately following the mention.
- not that this pattern requires a non-matching character after mention, so if it matters work around that.

**A cleaner pattern would use a feature called [look-ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html):**

```
@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+?(?![a-zA-Z0-9_.])
```

- (?!) is negative lookahead. Meaning "only match if it is NOT followed by this"
- named capture not required as lookahead does not consume the lookahead part.
- It supports multiple mention lookups by adding using non-greedy quantifier `+?`. This ensures that matched mention is as short as possible.

Lookaheads are a tad less known and may become a pain to read if pattern grows too long. But it is a useful tool to know.

**Full example using C#:**

```
string comment = "hi @fri.tara3^ @hjh not a mention @someone";
const String pattern = "@[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+?(?![a-zA-Z0-9_.])";
var matches = Regex.Matches(comment, pattern);

for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: thank you , how about finding multi @ like `"hi @fri.tara3^ @hjh"` am I must to use something like this: `comment=comment.Substring(indexofLastFind,...)`

Comment: Regex can find all matches for you in one pass. See updated example in answer.

Comment: you are magical, unbelievable !  thank you, thank you very much :*